# How do I build an iOS Framework with the FIT C++ library

Tags: ios, frameworks

I am trying to create a Swift wrapper for the FIT C++ `libFitSdkCppiOS.a` library but don't really know how to set things up with the mix of C++, Objective-C and Swift code.

Here is what I have done so far:
1.  Created a new target for the FITFramework
2.  Copied the `libFitSdkCppiOS.a` library and the associated cpp header files into the targets folder in Xcode
3.  Because you can't use a `Bridging-Header` file in Frameworks I am trying to figure out how what to do next.

I have seen a few posts about something called an umbrella header but have no idea what that is or what needs to be in it to get this to work.  Can someone please explain step by step what I need to do to create this Swift Wrapper and package it up as a framework that can be used by other projects.

1. Is the umbrella header the main framework header file, in this case the one called `FITFramework.h` ?
2. If not how do I create an umbrella header file and where does it need to be?
3. What should be in the umbrella header file?

FITFramework.h

```
//
//  FITFramework.h
//  FITFramework
//
//  Created by xxxx xxxxxxx on 7/6/18.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

//! Project version number for FITFramework.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double FITFrameworkVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for FITFramework.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char FITFrameworkVersionString[];

// In this header, you should import all the public headers of your framework using statements like #import <FITFramework/PublicHeader.h>
```

EDIT:
1.  How do I expose the Objective-C classes to Swift without using a Bridging-Header file ?

There are a few articles that mention the use of a module.map file but this seems to be to expose the C headers rather than the Objective-C headers to the Swift wrapper function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I figured it out - and it was hard to find any good or accurate guides.  I will write it up in more detail elsewhere and add a link at some point.

In the meantime - assuming your framework is call `XXXFramework` - you need to:

create a `XXXFrameworkPrivate` subdirectory in the `XXXFramework` folder with a `module.modulemap` file in it

add the private headers to the `module.modulemap` file like so

```
module FitFrameworkPrivate {
    header "../XXX.h"
    header "../YYY.h"
    header "../ZZZ.h"
    export *
}
```

create a `XXX.xcconfig` file with the following line 
`SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS = $(SRCROOT)/XXXFramework/XXXFrameworkPrivate`

set the project configuration to use this config file for both debug and release

add this line to your Swift classes

import `XXXFrameworkPrivate`

Basically this allows Swift classes to import the headers from the `module.modulemap` file instead of using a Bridging-Header file which can't be used in a Framework.

Watch out though - I have callbacks between the C++ classes, the Objective-C classes and the Swift classes and this creates a problem if your public class uses a protocol to communicate with one of the private Obj-C classes.  To avoid that add another public Swift class that talks to the Swift wrapper and only have that one public.

If anyone has a better way of doing it please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot! This answer was very useful to me as I had similar issue (to integrate the c fit sdk instead of the c++ fit sdk into a swift framework for macOS and iOS apps)

I'll just add the follow step I had to do, in case it helps someone:

When using the framework in a app that used Pods, I wasn't able to include the "Private" framework (necessary because it contains the c constant converted to swift constant like FIT_MESG_XXX) and the xcconfig are set by the Pods framework. Editing the Pods xcconfig worked, but clearly bad.

Eventually, I figured out you can just create a new xconfig with a `#include` and use that in the external app where you want to use like so (this is separate from the xcconfig you need to build the framework)

```
#include "../Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-iOSorMac/Pods-iOSorMacOSApp.debug.xcconfig"
SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS="$(SRCROOT)/fit-sdk-swift/RZFitFile/sdk" "$(SRCROOT)/fit-sdk-swift/RZFitFile/src"
```